# how to get return value in true condition

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, variables

I have a *controller code* like this, but I don't know how to *pass the variable* in `$date="dataInputan ['date']"` into the ViewSewing function of the code section: `$ date = ........;`
i try using return,,
but the this code can't get *true* condition if

**full code**

```
public function index2()
{
    if (isset($_POST['dataInputan'])) {
        $dataInputan = $_POST['dataInputan'];
        $date = $dataInputan['date'];
        $rst = $this->dataLineSewingModel->getSewingLine($date);
        echo json_encode($rst);
        //$this->session->set_flashdata('dateset', $date);
        return $date;
    } else {
        return date('Y-m-d');
    }
}


public function viewSewing($GroupID)
{
    //$date = $this->session->flashdata('dataset');
    $date = $this->index2();
    print_r($date);
    $data['getGroup'] = $this->dataLineSewingModel->getDetailLineSewing($GroupID, $date);
    $data['getTitle'] = $this->dataLineSewingModel->getTitleSewing($GroupID);
    $data['GroupID'] = $GroupID;
    $this->load->view('total_emp/lineSewingView', $data);
}
```

*please help me*

Comment: from where `ViewSewing()` is called?

Comment: @KUMAR : i call `ViewSewing()` in view page Sewing

Comment: You want to passing $date from index2 to $date in ViewSewing which is that 2 variable have the same value?
I think you can set $dataInputan = $_POST['dataInputan']; too in ViewSewing() function

Comment: please provide view code so other can help with your problem

Comment: @DaffaAkbari, i cant post the view, because the view is to long code

Comment: @heathscliff i try this, this code is work, but this get data _NULL_ and  _Undefined index: dataInputan_

Comment: are you using form post method and call the index2 controller ?

Comment: Yeah, I thinks it's because your index2 doesn't have any relations with ViewSewing. You can use CI flashdata to store $date (from index2) temporally, and then you can call the flashdata in ViewSewing

Comment: yes,, @DaffaAkbari

Comment: @heathscliff thanks again, i try this, and _flashdata_ cannot store into $date at viewSewing.. flashdata _null_

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to call controller viewSewing from page viewSewing but you want the data from index2.

I think you can do something like this.

```
public function index2($dataIn)
    {
        if (isset($dataIn)) {
            $dataInputan = $_POST['dataInputan'];
            $date = $dataInputan['date'];
            $this->dateAll = $dataInputan['date'];

            $rst = $this->dataLineSewingModel->getSewingLine($this->dateAll);
            echo json_encode($rst);
            
        }
    }
    
    public function ViewSewing($GroupID)
    {
        $dataInput = $this->input->post('dataInputan');
        $date = $dataInput['date'];

        $this->index2($dataInput);

        $data['getGroup'] = $this->dataLineSewingModel->getDetailLineSewing($GroupID, $date);
        $data['getTitle'] = $this->dataLineSewingModel->getTitleSewing($GroupID);
        $data['GroupID'] = $GroupID;
        $this->load->view('total_emp/lineSewingView', $data);
    }
```

Comment: i try this but this code still doesn't get the value from `dataInput`

Comment: I need the view code, just the one with form submit, you dont need to copy all the code

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function ViewSewing($GroupID)
    {
        
        if (isset($_POST['dataInputan'])) {
            
            //$_POST['dataInputan'] -> is array
            $dataInputan = $_POST['dataInputan'];
            $dateAll = $dataInputan['date'];
            $rst = $this->dataLineSewingModel->getSewingLine($dateAll);
            $json_data = json_encode($rst);
            
        }
        if($json_data!=''){
          $data['json'] = $json_data;
        }
        $data['getGroup'] = $this->dataLineSewingModel->getDetailLineSewing($GroupID, $date);
        $data['getTitle'] = $this->dataLineSewingModel->getTitleSewing($GroupID);
        $data['GroupID'] = $GroupID;
        $this->load->view('total_emp/lineSewingView', $data);
    }

//this extract the json_data and show in view page
    $result = json_decode($json, true));
```